# WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1 is ignored for debug

Tags: java, android

i know there is an answer for this warning case, but in my case is different, since i am not using this Dependency!

Important Note: i am importing a project from Eclipse to Android Studio. and there is no another error or warning.

Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'}
```

That is all

Comment: have you figured it out? I have a similar issue